# Scroll screen in EV3 Home Edition program

Tags: mindstorms, ev3-g

I'm using LEGO Mindstorms EV3 Home Edition program to program my robot. Typically a program becomes wider than the screen. However, no horizontal scrollbars appear on screen.

So how can I view and edit my entire program if there are no scrollbars? There is no vertical scrollbar, but for that I can use my mouse's scrollwheel.

[image: mindstorms]

Comment: There is a BUG with grey arrows.. sometimes they show, sometimes they don't. So, thank you, now I know I don't have to zoom out to be able to see my program!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the mouse, you can click on the gray arrows on the edges of the screen (indicated with red arrows below). You will need to close the Content Editor to be able to see the one on the right clearly.

Another option using the mouse is to use the "pan" tool. Click on the tool icon that looks like a hand (circled in red below). Then use it to click and drag anywhere in the work area.

You can also use the keyboard arrow keys. First click on any blank white space to make sure that no blocks are selected, then press the arrow keys to scroll.

[image: screenshot indicating arrows]

Comment: Thanks. Why would Lego want to follow conventions when they can come up with their own? :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can click your mouse on screen outside the blocks of your program and then use arrow keys to scroll the program

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for me, is using <kbd>SPACE</kbd> key. Press down and hold <kbd>SPACE</kbd> while dragging the programming canvas, the canvas should move with your cursor.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, and welcome to Bricks.SE!

Answer (score 0):

Use different editor as in mobile

Comment: Mobile devices lack almost all code blocks, so it's no use. Besides, they don't give the instructions for building and programming the robot.